# How can I add to NSMutableDictionary key NSIndexPath and value BOOL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary, key-value, nsindexpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C dictionary inserting a BOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108042/objective-c-dictionary-inserting-a-bool)

I need to add key-value pair NSIndexPath -> BOOL to NSMutableDictionary.How can I do this? It's really a problem for me. I can't use neither `setValue forKey` (because key must be NSString only) nor `setObject forKey` (because BOOL is a primitive and I cant'use `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` also because NSNumber is immutable and I need to change BOOL value).

So the question how can I add such a key-value pair with all the restrictions i have. Any ideas?

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1].. change to 1 or 0. Bam easiest way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the BOOL in a `NSNumber` as suggested in this answer: [Objective-C dictionary inserting a BOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108042/objective-c-dictionary-inserting-a-bool)

Comment: Best I can tell, the BOOL value is subject to mutation, so wrapping it into an NSNumber will not reflect the latest state of the BOOL that the NSNumber is meant to indicate.

Comment: ...why can't you just replace the NSNumber in the dictionary when you need to change it?

Comment: My guess (Lots of guessing with missing details…) is that the BOOL is a property or ivar on an object. That's why I thought it was an antipattern that would be pretty recognizable with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have to contain objects. There isn't a way around this. One way you could do this is to create a custom getter and setter method for the BOOL you need to manipulate so that it fetches and updates the value in the dictionary instead of in a property. Or, if you need to keep a property reference, you'll need to use KVO to keep the two values in sync, but that sounds like an antipattern. It might help if you described in more detail what your use case is, but I think those are your two options.